# Merge sort algorithm using array on std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, recursion, smart-pointers

**UPDATE:**

***Ok, I finally found where the problem is, but it turned out, that complete explanation of it, is much more complicated than taught, so it will take me some time to update my post.***

I'm trying to make merge sort algorithm using array allocated on std::unique_ptr.

When I run application it usually breaks and returns 0xC0000005 or throws as std::bad_alloc.

When I'm running it with debugger (form Code::Blocks IDE) it doesn't break , but some of data on result array are negative witch isn't correct(input array contains random value form 0 to 100).

I think some of memory is freed before I wanted, but all memory management is done by std::unique_ptr and in only using smart pointers to access dynamic memory.

Is it possible that std::move does not transfer ownership immediately, or is it something different?

I'm using: `void mergeSort(SmartPtrArray<T>& array_before)` to run merge sort.

**Here is fragment of my code:**

```
template <typename T>
struct SmartPtrArray
{
    SmartPtrArray() {}
    SmartPtrArray(int i): array(new T[i]), amount(i) {}
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> array;
    int amount;
};

namespace SortingAlgoritms
{

template <typename T>
void merge(SmartPtrArray<T>& array_a, SmartPtrArray<T>& array_b, SmartPtrArray<T>& result_array)
{
    if(result_array.array != nullptr)
        result_array.array.reset();
    std::unique_ptr <T[]> tmp (new T [array_a.amount+array_b.amount]);
    result_array.array = std::move(tmp);// now result_array is only pointer with ownership
    result_array.amount= array_a.amount + array_b.amount;


    if(array_a.array[array_a.amount-1] <= array_b.array[0])//1 case
    {
        for(auto i = 0; i < array_a.amount; i++)
            result_array.array[i] = array_a.array[i];
        for(auto i = array_a.amount; i < ( array_a.amount + array_b.amount ); i++)
            result_array.array[i] = array_b.array[i - array_a.amount];


    }
    else                                                    //2 case
    {
        auto j = 0;
        auto i = 0;
        for(i = 0; i <= array_a.amount; i++)
        {
            while(j < array_b.amount && array_b.array[j] <= array_a.array[i])
            {
                result_array.array[i+j] = array_b.array[j];
                j++;
            }
            result_array.array[i+j] = array_a.array[i];
        }
        while(j < array_b.amount && array_b.array[j] <= array_a.array[i-1])
        {
            result_array.array[i+j] = array_b.array[j];
            j++;
        }

    }
}

template <typename T>
void mergeSort(SmartPtrArray<T>& array_before, SmartPtrArray<T>& result, int begin, int end)
{
    SmartPtrArray<T> tmp_left;
    SmartPtrArray<T> tmp_right;
    int break_point=(end+begin)/2;;
    if(end-begin > 1)
    {
        mergeSort(array_before, tmp_left, begin, break_point);
        mergeSort(array_before, tmp_right, break_point, end);
        merge(tmp_left, tmp_right, result);
    }
    else
    {
        if(result.array!=nullptr)
            result.array.reset();
        SmartPtrArray<T> tmp(1);
        tmp.array[0] = array_before.array[begin];
        result.array=move(tmp.array);
        result.amount=1;
    }

}
template <typename T>
void mergeSort(SmartPtrArray<T>& array_before)
{
    SmartPtrArray<T> tmp_left;
    SmartPtrArray<T> tmp_right;
    int break_point=array_before.amount/2;
    if(array_before.amount!=1)
    {
        SmartPtrArray<T> result;
        mergeSort(array_before, tmp_left, 0, break_point);
        mergeSort(array_before, tmp_right, break_point, array_before.amount);
        merge(tmp_left, tmp_right, result);
        if(array_before.array!=nullptr)
            array_before.array.reset();
        array_before=std::move(result);
    }
}

}
```

**Example output with debugger:**

> Generating arrays
>
> Array Before sort: 40 22 24 21 39 10 80 44 8 20 21
>
> Result Array: 8 10 20 21 21
>   -1414812757 22 24
>   -1414812757
>   -1163005939

Comment: Thank you, yes I should use `reset()`. It didn't solved problem, however I've edited question.

Comment: Could you add the test code that attempts to sort the array?

Comment: Of course I will. Thanks for interest.
I actually found the line when program is crashing. It's     
std::unique_ptr <T[]> tmp (new T [array_a.amount+array_b.amount]);
in merge function.
Also negative values were caused by
while(j < array_b.amount /*&& array_b.array[j] <= array_a.array[i-1]*/)
(comment section is problem) after for loop in merge function.
Now sorting runs perfectly in Code::Blocks debugger, but it still crushes when on normal run.

I'm will update question as soon as possible.

Comment: Ok, I actually found where the problem is, but it turned out that complete explanation of it is much more complicated than taught, so it will take me some time to update my post.